# Generated CSS stylesheets ignored by IE9 and Firefox

Tags: css, code-generation, cross-browser

You can see what I'm building, and the source code here: http://eiskis.net/proot/pika/proot/

I'm generating both stylesheets and script files from multiple pieces. The styles themselves seem to work fine, but **Firefox and IE9 do not apply the styles at all**. The source code has the link correctly, and it takes me to the source code when I click the link in Firefox' source browser. JavaScript seems to be applied normally. On Chrome and Opera, both styles and behavior work as expected.

My initial thought was bad MIME types, but the headers should be passed correctly. Firefox also shows the type of the CSS file as text/css.

http://eiskis.net/proot/pika/helloworld/ and *docs/* are created with the same system, and the problem is also prevalent there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error in your CSS.

On line 142 of the generated CSS:

```
input[type="submit] { cursor: pointer;}
```

should be:

```
input[type="submit"] { cursor: pointer;}
```

Comment: That's it, just got it myself too. I should've put more effort into validation, I immediately assumed I was facing some very elaborate problem. It's fixed now.